# How can I set custom Server header with Tornado?

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, tornado

I noticed that my app returns this HTTP response header:

```
Server: TornadoServer/4.5.2
```

Is it possible to change it to custom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the RequestHandler.set_header() for the headers you want to add or change.
Here is an example

```
    RequestHandler.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    RequestHandler.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
    RequestHandler.set_header('Access-Control-Max-Age', 1000)
```

Comment: How does this work when using Flask with tornado? I'm getting `TypeError: unbound method set_header() must be called with RequestHandler instance as first argument (got str instance instead)`

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, I don't know where to implement this code which you describe above. I have torando and sockJS. I don't know which of this this two is responsible for giving Server : Tornado / 6.0.4 in response header. Can you please elaborate more, like where do I need to modify the code? Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`RequestHandler.set_default_headers()`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.set_default_headers)

Do note that setting such headers in the normal flow of request processing may not do what you want, since headers may be reset during error handling.

Here is the [source](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/_modules/tornado/web.html#RequestHandler.set_default_headers) from the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

you also can use `RequestHandler.set_header()`.

this method will change the finally return response header.